# Stata histogram with only one variable's value

Tags: stata

I want to draw a histogram using `hist` of a variable which takes only one value (0.85), and then use `hist` to show another variable in the background that is a distribution of the first one. For example,

```py
gen example_var = 0.85

hist example_var, percent xscale(range(0 1)) graphregion(color(white)) xtitle("Example Data")
```

The result is the following:

**Screenshot**
[image]

This distribution looks odd. It's unclear to me, not very informative, and cannot be used for my purpose.

I have tried to change width or bins to plot with the other graph, but I could not solve this.

I did this graph with R (extremely easy). However, I wish to know how do it also in Stata.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done. You just need to spell out more details to override defaults.

```
clear
set obs 1
gen var1 = 0.85
hist var1 , start(0) width(0.02) xsc(r(0 1)) xla(0 0.5 1) percent
```

The bin width here is arbitrary. I am imagining that you want in essence to see a spike, but as in your question `width()` is an option.